# python: how to check whether a value of an object is included in an array

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to make a text with python for commands, which is currently coded:

```
L=open('lp0.dat','w')
L.write('Maximize')
for i in range(ndof):
    L.write(' '+str(-grad_f[i]))
L.write('\n')
for i in range(ndof):
    if i==fix_index[i]:
        L.write('s.t 0 =')
        for j in range(ndof):
            if j==i:
                L.write(' 1')
            else:
                L.write(' 0')
        L.write('\n')
    elif i%2==0:
        L.write('s.t 0.1 >=')
        for j in range(ndof):
            if j==i:
                L.write(' 1')
            else:
                L.write(' 0')
        L.write('\n')
        L.write('s.t -0.1 <=')
        for j in range(ndof):
            if j==i:
                L.write(' 1')
            else:
                L.write(' 0')
        L.write('\n')
    else:
        L.write('s.t 0.15 >=')
        for j in range(ndof):
            if j==i:
                L.write(' 1')
            else:
                L.write(' 0')
        L.write('\n')
        L.write('s.t -0.15 <=')
        for j in range(ndof):
            if j==1:
                L.write(' 1')
            else:
                L.write(' 0')
        L.write('\n')
L.close()
```

It is supposed to write 2 lines with inequality signs in each iteration, but if the index i is same with an element of the array(fix_index) it should write just one line with equality sign. Yes, I know that I made this part wrong:

```
if i==fix_index[i]:
```

because it shows the Indexerror, naturally. The array(fix_index) is shaped like this:

```
fix_index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 28, 29, 30, 31]
```

So what I want is that in the iteration when index i is same with one of those numbers then it should write only one line with =, otherwise write two lines with >= and <=. I tried to check that with another small for command in the iteration but the code gets too messy and doesn't even make sense. So I'll need a way of how to check whether a number is same with an element of an array.

Comment: So, you want the `in` operator? `if i in fix_index:`? If not, please explain further.

Comment: @Kevin Well, that worked awkwardly easy. Thanks, so can I use the same thing to any kind of arrays, like 2D or array of strings?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `in` operator

```
fix_index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 28, 29, 30, 31]
if 28 in fix_index:
    print("28 is in fix_index")
```